# Как в python выводить уравнение с учетом знаков чисел в нем?

Tags: python

Моя программа высчитывает коэфициенты некого уравнения и выводит его на экран, получается такая штука:

```
ϕ1 = -2.27 + 3.29(x - 0.25) + -0.06(x - 0.25)³
```

Вопрос в том, как учитывать знаки чисел(+ и -), чтобы не было как в примере выше(там где -0.06)

Comment: покажите как вы это делаете, чтобы мы могли его (ваш код) отредактировать.

Comment: Покажите хоть как вы строку формируете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как один из вариантов

```
a = 'ϕ1 = -2.27 + 3.29(x - 0.25) + -0.06(x - 0.25)³'
m = a.replace('+ -', '- ')
print(m)
```

ответ

```
ϕ1 = -2.27 + 3.29(x - 0.25) - 0.06(x - 0.25)³
```

Answer (score 1):

Делается через формат строки. К примеру, таким образом

```
a = -1.0
b = 1.0
print(f'{a:+f}*a {b:+f}*x')
```

или так через `str.format()`:

```
print('{0:+f}*a {1:+f}*x'.format(a, b))
```

Вывод

```
-1.000000*a +1.000000*x
```